# Auto preview updating is paused in Xcode 11.2

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Solution 1:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

I am using Xcode.app only. I have cross-checked it's not Xcode-beta.app.

Solution 2:
 I have removed all the scripts in build phase-> run scripts

Tried this two solutions still not working.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?... What happens when you click 'Resume' ?

Comment: nothing is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall your current Xcode and install the latest stable version (11.2.1) from the app store. You need Catalina 10.15.1. It's working fine for me.

Comment: I will try bro.